# What´s that NSTextFieldCell in a NSTableview built by IB

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

If I drag a NSTableView in in my Viewcontroller in IB there is an Element "Text Cell" of Type NSTextFieldCell.

It cannot be deleted.
What´s the NSTextFieldCell for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Table View Programming Guide for Mac, Understanding Table Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TableView/TableViewOverview/TableViewOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000026i-CH2-SW1):

> Most tables are NSView based, which means that each cell is provided by an NSView subclass, often by NSTableCellView (or a subclass). Some tables are NSCell based, which means that each table cell is based on a subclass of NSCell. For the most part, NSCell-based tables are used to support legacy code; if you’re creating a new app, you want to use NSView-based tables.

The Text Cell is for NSCell-based table views.

Comment: thanks. My table is viewbased. therefore I have an own subclass of NSTableCellView. Is it normal, the Textcell cannot be deleted?

Comment: Yes this is normal and confusing.